# Hawk authentication in JMeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

can someone please tell me how to configure hawk authentication process (Hawk Auth ID , Hawk Auth Key ,Algorithm ) in JMeter ?

I tried to pass this values like hawk id , hawk key , algorithm through header manager but it gives unauthorized error. so I need to know the process to send this values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest for you would be using [Java implementation of HAWK protocol](https://blog.mozilla.org/services/2015/02/05/whats-hawk-and-how-to-use-it/) from a suitable JMeter's [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Example steps:

1. Drop [hawk-core.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.wealdtech.hawk/hawk-core) and all its [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (i.e. "lib" folder of your JMeter installation)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the jars up
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which required authentication
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def hawkClient = new com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkClient.
           Builder()
           .credentials(new com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkCredentials.Builder()
                   .keyId("your-hawk-hey-id")
                   .key("your-hawk-key")
                   .algorithm(Algorithm.SHA256)
                   .build())
           .build();

   def authorization = hawkClient.generateAuthorizationHeader(sampler.getUrl().toURI(), sampler.getMethod(), sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

   vars.put('authorization', authorization)
   ```
5. In the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) use `${authorization}` as the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header value